# Could not get the structure for packages in Allure Reporting

Tags: nunit, allure

I am trying to generate the allure reports , with specflow.json configuration
and the sample test case with tags

I don't see the "packages" in allure report are generating as hierarchy , can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

There is an open PR on this issue here.
https://github.com/unickq/allure-nunit/pull/38